# Why when I use fraction number, I got [LayoutConstraints] error. But when I round that number. The error gone

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitableview

I auto layout my view by code with `NSLayoutConstraint` to set my view's height and I have a weird error like this:
When I use `fraction number` like `324.867` to set my view's height. It raise an error `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints`.

But if I round `324.867` to `324`. The error is gone.

Can any one explain why it happens?

This is my code:

```
let estimateSizeOfTopic = CGSize(width: self.frame.width - 10.0, height: 1000.0)
let attributeOfTopic = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
let estimateHeight = NSString(string: topicTitle.text!).boundingRect(with: estimateSizeOfTopic, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeOfTopic, context: nil).height

NSLayoutConstraint(item: topicTitle, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: estimateHeight).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: topicTitle, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5.0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: topicTitle, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5.0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: topicTitle, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -5.0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: topicTitle, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: superView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -5.0).isActive = true
```

// My superView does not have any constraint on it...I coded that way because I want to auto set height of my superView's by my topicTitle height (Table View cell auto sizing)

The error happens at the first constraint.

```
//If I use this line of code. It raise an error
NSLayoutConstraint(item: topicTitle, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: estimateHeight).isActive = true

//If I use this line of code instead. The error is gone
NSLayoutConstraint(item: topicTitle, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: round(estimateHeight)).isActive = true
```

I rounded my `estimateHeight` because if I do not round it, it raise error..
But inspire of there is an error. Every things in my view still look right

This is what the debug windows said:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000484560 UITextView:0x7f9049080c00'It is a long established ...'.height == 324.867   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000285280 V:|-(5)-[UITextView:0x7f9049080c00'It is a long established ...']   (active, names: '|':SatacusWorld.PostViewCell:0x7f9049096a00'postIdentifier' )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800029fe50 UITextView:0x7f9049080c00'It is a long established ...'.bottom == SatacusWorld.PostViewCell:0x7f9049096a00'postIdentifier'.bottom - 5   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800029fcc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' SatacusWorld.PostViewCell:0x7f9049096a00'postIdentifier'.height == 334.8   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000484560 UITextView:0x7f9049080c00'It is a long established ...'.height == 324.867   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out why that error occurs.
Because I used auto sizing Table View by these two line of code

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
```

And in the background, `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` will calculate my cell height automatically and round that number to 1 decimal place

For example:

If my total height of cell is: `324.833`

It's will round that number to `324.8`

So that. The total height of cell (`324.833`) is larger then cell's height (`324.8`)

And to fix that error, I just round my number before `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` round it

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a curious bug, because the math in those errors adds up (literally).

However, it's not that surprising: Using the estimates in `boundingRect(with:options:attributes:context:)` in layout constraints and expecting it to match later with Auto Layout calculations can fail even with examples less precise than this. It's due to details of typography, and possibly details of how fonts are rendered at different scales.

You might want to ask, can you avoid setting a height constraint on this text view? Since you want the entire text to appear, make sure to set the `UITextView` property `scrollEnabled` to `false`. This will cause it to provide the correct size for its text to the Auto Layout engine at the appropriate time (when the horizontal bounds are set). If it's in a cell, using automatic cell sizing, then it should size itself and the cell correctly. Hope this helps.